# Convert python construction to jython 2.1

Tags: python, jython

In python there is construction like:

```
dic=dict(item.split('=') for item in list)
```

but jython 2.1 dont understand it.
How can i convert it to jython code?
Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned that this is related to WebSphere in a comment to Łukasz Rogalski's answer. According to this article it should be possible to use newer versions of Jython: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1207_vansickel/1207_vansickel.html.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause for your error is lack of support for [PEP 289 -- Generator Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) which was introduced in Python 2.4 and wasn't even in language specification when Python 2.2 was latest version.

You may easily work around it by using standard list comprehension

```
dic = dict([item.split('=') for item in list])
```

Btw. Is there any particular reason you want to run [16 years old interpreter](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/NEWS.html) and not [latest one](https://hg.python.org/jython/file/412a8f9445f7/NEWS)?

Comment: Because of IBM websphere using it.. Can you help with this too please: " ".join('-s' +  i + '=' + dict[i] for i in dict) how deal with this too? Thanks

Comment: I deal with it like:
for i in dict: out=" ".join('-s' + i + '=' + dict[i]) 
But now there is another error : NameError: dict
what a kind of junk..(

Comment: The `dict` built-in type was added in Python 2.2: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.